# Vertical scrollable image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to make a vertical scrollable image gallery on the page text very similar to this website https://kontorkontor.dk/ can you help me figure out how to make it?

Comment: [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, questions asking for recommendations are generally considered
 [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site. Generally, [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried so far and where you are stuck tend 
 to generate the most helpful answers along with any [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) you have gathered.

Comment: Provide the code what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the text as position fixed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>bruh</title>
    <style>
        
        img {
            height: 65vh;
            width: auto;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            margin: 200px 0;
        }

        ul {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
        }

        ul li {
            list-style: none;
            font-size: 150px;
            font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <ul>
        <li>Hey guys</li>
        <li>+31 6 5342674</li>
        <li>hoi@google.com</li>
    </ul>

    <section class="gallery">
        <img src="http://juliecristobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/20180601_Emma_09_0509-copie.jpg" alt="image">
        <img src="http://juliecristobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/20180701_Schon__010127.jpg" alt="image">
        <img src="http://juliecristobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/SK_FW18_ADDITIONALPIC_06_WEB.jpg" alt="image">
        <img src="http://juliecristobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/20180415_Elodie_05_1176-2-copie-1.jpg" alt="image">
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: perfect, thanks so much!

Comment: and if i wanted to scroll the images horizontaly? thx

Comment: Set the images on display: inline-block. You could add a margin on the right to make it more beautiful. 

Comment: Oh and set white-space on nowrap. And if I was you I would use javascript for this.